# How to split a column along with its contents?

Tags: ubuntu, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

In LibreOfficeCalc i have a single column with 2 values like this

[image]

I have to split this into 2 as given below:

[image]

How can i do this??

Comment: This might be better suited to http://superuser.com/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Highlight the column / section of data you want to split;
- Select Data > Text to columns from the menu;
- From the Text to columns dialog, specify Separated by Other, and enter `/` as the separator;
- Click OK.